# Unwanted annotation in map ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I am trying to annotate some locations in map using MapBox. and its done.
But the problem is some other annotations are seen in map without any reference, i.e we cant click on it and when i zoom in/zoom out it disappears. 
Am only try to create two annotations including user location.
How this happen?
is it because any reusing of annotation?

[image]

Some code snippets used:

1) creating annotation in loop

```
    MGLPointAnnotation *point = [[MGLPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = coordinate;
    point.title = location;
    NSString *altString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mIsNSDictionary(response)?[response objectForKey:kKeyAlt]:response];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:kKeyLocationLatLonNAltInBaidu,coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude,[altString floatValue]];
    point.subtitle = str;
    [self.arrayAnnotations addObject:point];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
```

Note: self.arrayAnnotations contains only 2 points

2) Delegate method for annotation

```
-(MGLAnnotationImage *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView imageForAnnotation:(id <MGLAnnotation>)annotation {
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MGLPointAnnotation class]] && [self.arrayAnnotations containsObject:annotation]) {
        NSString *reuseIdentifier = [self makeIdentifierString:annotation];
        MGLAnnotationImage *annotationImage = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationImageWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (!annotationImage) {
            annotationImage = [MGLAnnotationImage annotationImageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kImageNameMarker] reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        }
        return annotationImage;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: then it will be nice to show some relevant code here.

Comment: some codes used for annotation are included now

Comment: Where are you creating the annotations? Can you post the function that creates it? Are you sure you're not calling it twice or creating new annotation somewhere else?

Comment: yes. my code only creates two annotations in map. also maps [self.mapView annotations] method gives only 2 annoations.

Comment: It would help if you could show your loop and not just the code inside it. Also, please show how your loop is called. The extra annotation is on zero degrees longitude like the annotation in the Bight of Africa, so I think they may be inter related.

Comment: i think its because of zero degree coordinates. if i hardcoded the coordinate with a fixed value the extra coordinates are not seen.